# Open specific folder with intent on Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open a specific folder with Intent but it only opens the recent files like this:

[Recent Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLWef.jpg)

My code (updated):

```
 //path i want to open: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.pytorch.demo.objectdetection/files/Pictures/saved_images

    String myDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Android/data/org.pytorch.demo.objectdetection/files/Pictures/saved_images" + "/";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(myDir);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is no support in Android for "open a specific folder". Also, `file/*` is not a valid MIME type, and `myDir` is not a valid string representation of a `Uri` to parse.

Comment: Ok! I've changed the type for "*/*" and make a Uri from myDir. But it keeps opening the recent files (code updated to as it is now)

Comment: Sorry, but there is no support in Android for "open a specific folder".

Comment: `Open specific folder with intent on Android Java` Wrong title. You mean: with ACTION_VIEW. But ACTION_VIEW is not used for folders to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

On an Android 11 device ACTION_VIEW can be used to let the Files or Documents app open in a specified directory.

Code has been published before.

One can only browse. Not pick a folder or file.